# Is it possible to extract the Schema ID when using KStream processing?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am processing messages from sourceTopic to a targetTopic using KStream (using **map** method). In the **map** method, I am generating a new schema (since i need to extract explicit fields) for the targettopic using the incoming messages, but since the KStream operation is per message, i wish to avoid regenerating the schema for every message and would instead want to cache the schemaID of the incoming messages (for both Key and Value) and generate new targetschema only if the source Schema changes.

Is there a way to do this via the KStream object or from the Key/Value objects used in the **map** method

**Update:**

I was not able to get the schema ID for my above use case, as a workaround I cached the schema into a local variable and checked on each iteration if it changed and process further as required.

Answer (score 0):

You only will have access to the ID if you use Serde.Bytes; after the records are deserialized, you'll only have access to the Schema.

The AvroSerdes from Confluent already cache the ids, though.

Comment: Well I am looking for a way to get the schema inside the **map** method of the kstream object, for the key and value of the incoming message. I will be caching that schemaid and decide if i want to regenerate my target schema (since I modifying it and in case of any evolution only would i want to regenerate it)
This is my setup of the kstream :
**KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> inputStream = builder.stream(sourceTopic, Consumed.with(keyGenericAvroSerde,valueGenericAvroSerde));**